# Changing blog information (such as blog title) using Google Blogger API

Tags: php, api, blogger

I'm using the [v1.0 PHP API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html), but an answer for any of the languages/versions will suffice (I'll be able to figure it out in PHP.)

Google's Blogger API shows the ability to perform CRUD operations, but nothing else.

**Is it possible to change any blog preferences/settings/options, specifically something like changing the blog title via API?**

I haven't seen anything in my searches, but it seems like something that should be available.

Comment: I asked the [same question on the Blogger Dev group](http://groups.google.com/group/bloggerdev/browse_thread/thread/0dc7db012477f142), but I didn't really understand the answer. Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. After looking through [the 2.0 protocol documentation](https://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) it's clear that you can only interact with blog posts and comments, not with the blog's metadata.

As for the answer you got at the Blogger dev group, the person seems to be saying it's possible to retrieve the current title, but it's not possible to change it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it might be possible (can't try it right now) by using the GData API - for a reference see esp. the updating an entry part at https://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html

You need to combine that with the description [here](http://idratherhack.blogspot.com/2011/06/howto-change-blogger-settings-with.html) (which is/does exactly what you are asking for) and the URL you got for an answer (i.e. `https://www.blogger.com/feeds/*[blogId]*/settings`) although that answer seems to indicate it is not possible right now. Since these are contradicting each other I would definitely give it a try.